# How to take mysqldump with Generated column?

Tags: mysqldump, mysql-5.7, mariadb-10.3

I am getting below error while importing the dump,

> ERROR 3105 (HY000) at line 82: The value specified for generated
>   column 'column_name' in table 'table_name' is not allowed.

When I describe the table with error, there are some generated columns in it.

> option_type         | varchar(45)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    | VIRTUAL
>   GENERATED

What is the correct command to use when taking mysql dump for the database contains generated column?

MySQL server source and destination version:

> mysqld Ver 5.7.26 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))

MariaDB mysqldump CLI version:

> mysqldump Ver 10.17 Distrib 10.3.12-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a problem when using mysqldump from MariaDB with virtual generated columns.
MariaDB's mysqldump apparently dumps the generated values, but MySQL only accepts `DEFAULT` as value for a virtual generated column.

It seems like you need to use MySQL's mysqldump to correctly dump and restore virtual generated columns on a MySQL server.

The bug was also reported [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79148).

---

What I do as a workaround, is replace the virtual column in the dump:

```
sed -i 's/GENERATED ALWAYS AS .* VIRTUAL/NOT NULL/' mydump.sql
```

then restore the dump, then drop/add the generated column again:

```
mysql -e "ALTER TABLE foo DROP COLUMN bar;\
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar VARCHAR(255) AS ...;"
```

Comment: Please note that the sed workaround above breaks the dump if it contains MySQL's `help_topic` table. Consider editing the regex by adding the comma: `sed -i 's/GENERATED ALWAYS AS .* VIRTUAL,/NOT NULL,/' mydump.sql`

Answer (score 2):

We were able workaround by creating the dump not with `mysqldump` but https://github.com/Smile-SA/gdpr-dump which is based on a PHP base dump tool.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to do it by splitting the main `mysqldump` command into steps :

- Drop all tables (if you are not already using the `--add-drop-database`       parameter in your original `mysqldump` command)
- Add the parameter `--ignore-table=your_schema.your_table` to your original `mysqldump` command
- After this one ran, use a new `mysqldump` command to create only the table structure :

  ```
  mysqldump --no-data ... your_schema your_table
  ```
- Use a `mysql` command to run the proper `ALTER` on your_table (you want to change the type for a basic one) for example :

  ```
  mysql ... -D your_schema -e "ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN your_column1 boolean default null, MODIFY COLUMN your_column2 boolean default null;"
  ```
- Finally, use a `mysqldump` command to only fill the table (not create it) :

  ```
  mysqldump --no-create-info ... -e your_schema your_table
  ```

Hope it helps, have a great day !